# I'm trying to execute SOQL queries in my android app but keep getting AuthFailureError everytime

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I also try to simply run the template app included in salesforce sdk but still i am getting auth faliure error.

My code is :
api_version used is v35.0.

```
sendRequest("SELECT Name From CONTACTS");

private void sendRequest(String soql) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

RestRequest restRequest = RestRequest.getRequestForQuery(getString(R.string.api_version), soql);

if(restClient!=null) {
restClient.sendAsync(restRequest, new RestClient.AsyncRequestCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(RestRequest request, RestResponse result) {
    }

    @Override public void onError(Exception exception) { exception.printStackTrace(); }
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's has been solved,i need to give the permission of refresh token in bootconfig file as the soql query auth based on refresh token of user.